# vertical color gradient

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-animation, iphone-sdk-3.2

Horizontal gradient is working fine. Is there any way to get a vertical color gradient from horizontal gradient?
I have seen a related question regarding this where they did this by rotating the frames.

Is there any simpler way to achieve a vertical gradient?

Answer (score 79):

The default *startPoint* and *endPoint* would have the gradient display your colors from top to bottom (which in my mind is a *vertical* gradient). If you want the gradient to display from left to right (again in my mind this is a *horizontal* gradient), use this code on your *CAGradientLayer*:

```
  [gradientLayer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
  [gradientLayer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];
```

A 3D transform is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

How about rotating it 90º?

**edit**  judging from your comment, it seems that you're doing this via `CAGradientLayer`.  `CAGradientLayer` is a subclass of `CALayer`, which has a `transform` property.  This `transform` property takes a `CATransform3D`, which is a struct that represents some sort of linear transformation to be applied to the layer (such as scaling, translation, or rotation).

So really you just need to [make a rotational `CATransform3D`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CATransform3DMakeRotation) and set it as the `transform` property of your `CAGradientLayer`.

You could probably also make this work by fiddling with the `startPoint` and `endPoint` (which would actually probably be simpler).

Comment: I used gradient.startpoint and gradient.endpoint for rotating... is this ok...?  

I need 180 degree rotation.. shall I use the same logic as above.